# Disable/Prevent locking computers with GPO

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I am trying to figure out a way of disabling locking from a computer lab using GPOs. All the computers are running Windows 8.1. What I am trying to achieve is for the computers to:

- Never lock because of timeout
- Remove the lock option from the taskbar and from "CTRL+ALT+DEL" screen
- Disable the "Win+L" command from locking the computer

Is there a way of doing all of this with just GPOs? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can prevent the lock with the following GPO:

> User Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Ctrl+Alt+Del
>   Options\Remove Lock Computer

It will also disable Win+L and the computer won't be locked after the monitor times out for example.

Comment: To add: if doing it to an OU with lab computers, create the GPO for that OU and enable loopback processing, or the User Config portion in the answer won't apply to the computers.